# -CGI script not getting executed

Tags: debian, bash, web-server, apache2, cgi

0

I'm trying to make a simple form where you can introduce you're name and upon hitting the submit button you get redirected to a page where it says "Hello name_that_was_submited!". I did the index.html page and activated the CGI module of Apache but I only made it output the QUERY_STRING env variable just so I can see that everything is setup ok. And after writing a name in the form and hitting submit, my browser just opened a txt file with the CGI code in it. My assumption was that I setup the CGI module wrong but everything I tried to fix it failed.

First I tried to modify the main configuration file, (I use the debian 10 distribution), like so

```
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin/">
   Option +ExecCGI
   Require all granted
   Addhandler cgi-script .cgi
</Directory>
```

It didn't work. Deleted it form main config file and tried it in a bunch of other files( the way debian deals with the configuration really confuses me). Finally I got some results by writing that in the /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf file under `<VirtualHost>` as it displayed the code in the browser and not in a different txt file, yet it should've displayed the content of the QUERY_STRING var.

The docs are very confusing since the way the configuration is done for me is very different than what they describe ( I don't even have an httpd.conf file as main configuration file) so I am quite stumped. Any help would be much appreciated.

I should also mention that the cgi script is in Bash because this is a homework for collage and we are required to write everything in Bash.